# IntellJ Idea with Python: Ctrl + Right does move only one space

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I'm developing a python project with IntelliJ Idea, using the Python-plugin (which to my knowledge gives the same functionality as PyCharm).

In [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it clearly says

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.

so I switched my project from tabs to spaces as indentation method. Now when I have my cursor in the beginning of a line that is indented twelve spaces and I want to move the cursor four spaces to the right, my intuition was to press `Ctrl + Right` to move four spaces at once. Unfortunately it moves only one space, which feels very unnatural for me and is bothersome since it takes twelve key presses to get where I want.

Is there a way to make IntelliJ Idea move four spaces in this case? I looked through the settings dialog, but couldn't find something.

Comment: can you not use tab?

Comment: No, that adds four spaces to the left of the cursor. I merely want to move the cursor position, without changing the content of the file.

Comment: Interestingly, the same behavior in a Java-file works differently - cursor jumps to beginning of text. Not exactly what I would expect (just four positions like if there were tabs), but still it is soo much more usefull - if not even better (you actually save 11 keypress).
Someone from the IntelliJ team here that knows why this was implemented this way?